# How do I scale a graphics object by global coordinates in PixiJS?

Tags: javascript, graphics, pixi.js

I have a [PIXI.Container](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html) object that I need to scale straight up-and-down, by the Y axis of the camera. The object itself is rotated, so I don't want to scale by local co-ordinates.

This will scale the object by local co-ordinates:

```
container.scale.y = scaleFactor;
```

How do I scale it by global coords by this scale factor? I'm assuming I can use `container.worldTransform` somehow, but I don't understand how to use this.

Comment: Please create working example in jsfiddle / codesandbox / codepen etc. Then it will be easier to propose concrete changes in code.

Comment: @domis86 see the program here: https://ccnmtl.github.io/astro-simulations/eclipsing-binary-simulator/ and change the "Inclination" slider. You can see how the plane scales along its local axis, and not the camera perspective's axis. The line that corresponds to this scaling operation is here: https://github.com/ccnmtl/astro-simulations/blob/master/eclipsing-binary-simulator/src/BinarySystemView.jsx#L407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making two separate PIXI Containers: one for rotation, and an outer one for scaling. As suggested here: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/46497-how-do-i-scale-a-graphics-object-by-global-coordinates-in-pixijs/?do=findComment&comment=255423